# Trying to automate fdisk but when put into a shell script it will not write

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, partition

I am trying to automate some disk partitioning into a script i am creating but when i put the code into a .sh file it will not partition whereas if typed into the terminal manually it will work perfectly.
This is my code:

```
fdisk /dev/sda <<< "n" <<< "p" <<< "1" <<< "" <<< "+500M" <<< "t" <<< "ef" <<< "w"
```

this works fine when put straight into terminal but will not save changes when run from a shell script.

All this has been tested from within an archlinux live iso.

Comment: This was answered on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/332252/how-to-create-and-format-a-partition-using-a-bash-script)

Comment: `sfdisk` and `parted` are more script/automation friendly than `fdisk`